# How can I fix images being slow to load?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using Images.asset() in my Flutter project and the images are stored in the same Solutions Folder and have been compressed.
However, when scrolling through, it takes time for the images to load and more time for the images to load again once you go back to the same pageview.

[Here's a link to how it looks like](https://giphy.com/gifs/TJUMbjT5X5c2LAapVV)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this is a ListView.builder(), if am I correct, you can set a value, eg. 500, in the `cacheExtent` propriery, this will hold some data and will avoid destroy your previous content.